# Access component inside on ng-template

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have a component inside of an ng-template.  What is the best way to access it to call methods? I'm currently running into an issue where it is always undefined or unreachable with the normal methods I would have used to access it.

```
<ng-template #template>
<app-planned-expense-edit-form #editform
                               (save)="onPlannedItemSave($event)"
                               (isHidden)="onIsHidden($event)">

</app-planned-expense-edit-form>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With , you can define template content that is only being rendered by Angular when you, whether directly or indirectly, specifically instruct it to do so, allowing you to have full control over how and when the content is displayed.
I suggest using  instead of using  because the  can be used to hold directives without creating an HTML element.

and rewrite your code like this

```
<ng-template #template [ngIf]="true">
<app-planned-expense-edit-form #editform
                               (save)="onPlannedItemSave($event)"
                               (isHidden)="onIsHidden($event)">

</app-planned-expense-edit-form>
</ng-template>
```

and if you want to access to these element in TS using @ViewChild with `{ static: true }` configuration. The `{ static: true }` option was introduced to support creating embedded views on the fly.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck using ng-template. It's a third party control that will not take ng-container.

Comment: You can use a simple trick to solve the problem. I changed the above code. I hope it solves your problem

Comment: If I correctly interpret the "trick" as being to add [NgIf]="true" to the ng-template, then while it gives access via @ViewChildren, it also duplicates all of the items being rendered  within ng-template.

Answer (score 2):

We got into a similar issue where we wanted to selectively render the contents of `<ng-template>`, meaning stuff inside `ng-template` shouldn't always be visible.

Consider below example:

```
<ng-template #templRef>
  <div>
    <hello #helloRef name="{{ name }}"></hello>
  </div>
  ... other child comps
</ng-template>
```

After the template rendered, we wanted to get reference of "Hello Comp" and call some of it's method.

The reference `helloRef` would only be accessible if its present/rendered in the DOM.

When we access the `helloRef` in the handler which enables the template with `templRef`, it comes `undefined`. (Angular has still got to render the the comp and get its reference).

**We need to wait for the change detection to happen or "force the change detection" in the handler which shows the template.**

```
@ViewChild('templRef') templRef;
@ViewChild('helloRef') helloRef;

constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    // other stuff
}

templateShowHandler() {
  // logic to show the template
  this._cdr.detectChanges();
  console.log('templRef', this.templRef);
  console.log('helloRef', this.helloRef);
}
```

---

> Dummy Example

app.component.html

---

```
<ng-template #templRef>
  <div>
    <hello #helloRef name="{{ name }}"></hello>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngIf="showTempl">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templRef"> </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<button (click)="toggleShow()">ToggelShow</button>
```

app.component.ts

---

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  showTempl = false;
  @ViewChild('templRef') templRef;
  @ViewChild('helloRef') helloRef;

  constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  toggleShow() {
    this.showTempl = !this.showTempl;
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
    console.log('templRef', this.templRef);
    console.log('helloRef', this.helloRef);
  }
}
```

Please check the above dummy code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g5fcgn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

***In case manual change detection doesn't work, please try using the reference under a `setTimeout` callback under the template show handler.
`ChangeDetectorRefInstance.detectChanges()` will run change detection for current and its child comps, `setTimeout()` will run detection for the whole app.***